# How Can I Maintain DI Pattern of a Results Writer, with 2 different results sets?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

Note: I am note sure how to phrase the title

This is pseudo code of my Project that I am working on. For conciseness I have left out some details.

I have a 2 types of Consumer classes. One is inherited from the other and does a some extra things.

Consumer has a thread that runs a queue of tasks.

I have a IProducer that I pass in. It fires events, Consumer listens for those and then adds methods from IDoer to the queue.

I have had a IResultsWriter interface for writing results of the IDoer. Right now it just writes to a file (using CSVHelper) but I would like to allow other options in the future hence the interface, such as REST, or SQL etc.

I am trying to keep my API as Dependency injection compliant as possible.

My problem is that my derived Consumer class adds some extra properties to the results set. The Results set produced from IDoer are not changed. (these are added in the Consumer).

Right not it looks like my only option is to do away with my interface and pass in a different concrete class to each consumer. Consumer would get ResultsWriter and Consumer_WithExtra would get ResultWriter_WithExtra

Is there another approach I can take so I can still maintain my DI of ResultsWriter to allow other ways of writing in the future.

```
public class Main
{

    public RunThese()
    {
        Consumer A =  new Consumer(new Producer(), new Doer(), new ResultWriter());
        Consumer_WithExtra = new Consumer_WithExtra(new Producer(), new Doer(), new ResultWriter_WithExtra());

    }

}


public class Consumer
{

    public Consumer(IProducer producer, IDoer Doer, IResultsWriter writer)
    {

    }   

    private void DoTriggeredByProducer()
    {       
        write(results); 
    }


    protected virtual void write(List<DoerResult> results)
    {
        writer.write(results);
    }
}



public class Consumer_WithExtra : Consumer
{

    public string ExtraSomething {get; set;}

    public Consumer_WithExtra(IProducer producer, IDoer doer, IResultsWriter writer) : base (producer, doer, writer)
    {

    }   

    private void DoTriggeredByProducer()
    {
        //** Need to get Extra something to the 
        write(results)

    }

    protected override void write(List<DoerResult> results)
    {

        List<DoerResult_WithExtra> convertedResults =ConvertResults(results)

        writer.write(convertedResults);
    }

    private List<DoerResult_WithExtra> ConvertResults(List<DoerResult> results)
    {
        List<DoerResult_WithExtra> convertedResults = new List<DoerResult_WithExtra>();
        foreach(var r in results)
        {
            convertedResults.Add(new DoerResult_WithExtra(r) { ExtraProperty = this.ExtraSomething }
        }

        return convertedResults;
    }
}


public class DoerResult
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int BlahBlah {get; set;}
    public int BlahBlah {get; set;} 

}

public class DoerResult_WithExtra : DoerResult
{
    public string ExtraProperty {get; set;} 
}

public interface IResultsWriter()
{
    public void write(List<DoerResult> results);    
}

public class ResultWriter : IResultsWriter
{
    public virtual void write(List<DoerResult> results)
    {
        //** at a lost here
    }
}

public class ResultWriter_WithExtra : ResultWriter
{
    public override void write(List<DoerResult> results)
    {
        //** at a lost here
    }
}
```

Comment: In C#, you can easily evolve your interface with Extension Methods.

Comment: Could you elaborate has to how this would be helpful in this situation?

Comment: Extension Methods would allow you to add your additional methods to the interface's contract without creating a new derived type.  You can find out more about extension methods by reading https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: But an extension method on an Interface doesn't allows me to access anything in the base class that is not defined in the interface correct? How does that help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of changes I'd make. First I'd make Consumer an abstract class that accepts a generic, then put your two Consumers on top of that.

```
public abstract class Consumer<T>
{
    protected IResultWriter<T> _writer;
    public Consumer(IResultWriter<T> writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }   

    private void DoTriggeredByProducer()
    {       
        //write(results); 
    }


    public virtual void write(List<T> results)
    {
        _writer.write(results);
    }
}

public class Consumer_WithoutExtra : Consumer<DoerResult>
{

    public Consumer_WithoutExtra(IResultWriter<DoerResult> writer) : base(writer)
    {
    }   

    private void DoTriggeredByProducer()
    {       
        //write(results); 
    }


    public virtual void write(List<DoerResult> results)
    {
        _writer.write(results);
    }
}



public class Consumer_WithExtra : Consumer<DoerResult_WithExtra>
{

    public string ExtraSomething {get; set;}

    public Consumer_WithExtra(IResultWriter<DoerResult_WithExtra> writer) : base(writer)
    {
    }   

    private void DoTriggeredByProducer()
    {
        //** Need to get Extra something to the 
        //write(results);

    }

    public override void write(List<DoerResult_WithExtra> results)
    {
        _writer.write(results);
    }

    private List<DoerResult_WithExtra> ConvertResults(List<DoerResult> results)
    {
        List<DoerResult_WithExtra> convertedResults = new List<DoerResult_WithExtra>();
        foreach(var r in results)
        {
           // convertedResults.Add(new DoerResult_WithExtra(r) { ExtraProperty = this.ExtraSomething });
        }

        return convertedResults;
    }
}
```

Then I would setup your IResultWriter as a generic as well

```
public interface IResultWriter<T>
{
    void write(List<T> results);
}

public class ResultWriter : IResultWriter<DoerResult>
{
    public virtual void write(List<DoerResult> results)
    {
        foreach(var r in results)
            Console.WriteLine(r.Name);
    }
}

public class ResultWriter_WithExtra : IResultWriter<DoerResult_WithExtra>
{
    public virtual void write(List<DoerResult_WithExtra> results)
    {
        foreach(var r in results)
            Console.WriteLine(r.Name + ", " + r.ExtraProperty);
    }
}
```

That should clean up your DI so you are passing in new Consumer_WithExtra and new ResultWriter_WithExtra, hiding the generics, or new Consumer_WithoutExtra, and new ResultWriter

I have a sample of this running at http://rextester.com/JONL58320

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it your problem is that the IResultWriter's only requirement is that it can write DoResults whereas you want it to be able to write other things as well.

In this case you can:

1. Move the writing logic onto the DoResult class so the writer can just call it
2. Have that class expose its properties in a strongly typed way so the Writer doesn't have to resort to guessing the type or reflection. eg a `List<Property> Doresult.Properties`
3. Have the writer use reflection to write any object
4. Get funky with generics!

The problem with generics is they tend to work their way up the chain.

So at the bottom we have

```
public interface IResultWriter<T>
{
    void write(List<T> results);
}
```

This means each resultwriter knows about the type passed in so can use the extra property. But! you the also have to match up some of the other classes. Potentially all the way to the top of your graph

```
public interface Consumer<T>
{

    public Consumer(IProducer<T> producer, IDoer<T> Doer, IResultsWriter<T> writer)
    {

    }   

    private void DoTriggeredByProducer()
    {       
        write(results); 
    }


    protected virtual void write(List<T> results)
    {
        writer.write(results);
    }
}
```

However!! on the whole I would suggest an alternate approach. Constructors are not inherited. so there's no reason every Consumer needs to have an IResultWriter or indeed any form of ResultWriter other than you are inheriting from a base class which demands one.

Don't Inherit, instead have an interface and compose.

```
public class Consumer_WithExtra : IConsumer
{
    public Consumer_WithExtra(
        IProducer producer, 
        IDoer doer
        )

    private void DoTriggeredByProducer()
    {
        //** whatever the hell I want to do with whatever I want to inject
    }
}
```

Comment: I am confused by your last edit. I have a lot of code in Consumer, but I only need to alter a small portion if it. If I had Consumer_WithExtra Implement an Interface, I would have a lot of duplicate code. Also Consumer and Consume_WithExtra are at the top of my API graph. 

Further, Consumer and Consumer_WithExtra both need to write. Are so how would they get a Writer?

Comment: hmm its difficult to say without seeing your full code of course, but its really inheritance which is trapping you here rather than your interfaces. Composition doesn't trap you this way, but of course you would have to find other ways to avoid code duplication. Perhaps wrapping a Consumer, or splitting the logic inside consumer into further classes which can be injected where required